# How to add alt tags to images in Kentico

Tags: kentico

I do not have access to the code and need to add alt tags to images. We use Kentico as our CMS. I have tried adding decriptions in the Properties tab but the description does not show up in the HTML. Is it possible to add alt tags to images already in Kentico? If not, how do I add alt tags to images before I upload to Kentico?

Comment: Susan, you may have to be more specific as to how and where you're adding images to your page/site. The technique to add alt tags can vary based on where and how your adding images.

Comment: I add images to Kentico in these ways: uploading to the Image Library directly; onto a page via the Image Library; in to an image widget via the Image Library. We also have structured pages where I access the image from the Image Library and it has an alt tag field, which solves my problem for those images. I am open to switching up my process if that helps.

Comment: Can you be more specific about those items?  Are the controls URL selectors or file upload or attachments?

Comment: We upload files to the Media Library.